# RESTful way of File Uploading

Tags: rest, openrasta

I want to implement file upload in RESTful way using openrasta but not able to find proper way to implement it.There are few ways like using Ajax file upload or using Iframe which i could find.

Can anybody suggest any way of doing this or provide me some resources from where i can refer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not feel anything like this question is without any research or it is unclear.

Comment: Added an answer anyway, but there is already some answers that cover this partially on stackoverflow. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=upload+file+openrasta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you're trying to build file uploading in an html environment.

You have two choices.

Use an HTML form to upload the file.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/files" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="file" name="filename" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

You can map that in OR very easily. Your handler would look like this:

```
public object Post(IFile filename) { /* do something with the file */ }
```

You can't do ajax-based file upload with progress bars as there is no way in pure xmlhttprequest to manipulate binary files. If you go down the route of using a flash / silverlight control behind the scene, you'll just need to make sure you post the content of the file to `/files` as in the previous example, the easiest way being to send the content with a Content-Type http header of application/octet-stram, and the same handler code will just work.

Comment: Actually i want to send http headers like authentication which is possible using Ajax request.Is there any way i can handle this with the example you given.

Comment: authentication is completely unrelated, that's the role of http authentication itself, the browser takes care of it for you. What you cannot do at all without relying on a flash or silverlight control is to send an ajax request through xmlhttprequest, add http headers *and* send a file. That just is not possible.

Comment: I tried the example you given that is using IFile as parameter in handler method but it did not work for me.Openrasta was throwing the exception "An exception was thrown while processing a pipeline contributor Openrasta" So i modified the handler method 

`public OperationResult Post(IEnumerable<IMultipartHttpEntity> entities)` same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190537/uploading-with-multipart-form-data-using-openrasta-and-imultiparthttpentity it worked for me.

Comment: You'd have to lok at the log to find what the issue was with your IFile code, or at least give a stack trace.